# Chrome ARC unlimitedStorage limited to 1024 MB

Tags: google-chrome-arc

In manifest.json file unlimitedStorage permission is declared, however my app cannot write more than 1 GB, is this an intended behaviour?
is there any additional permission?

Comment: What happens when you attempt to write more than 1 GB? Do you just get an error, or is the app data wiped on next restart?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is intended behavior, but it could fall out of other system limits. There are no other permissions I know of to control storage quotas.

I took a quick look, and there doesn't seem to be a limit imposed by ARC. We interact with the Android code at the filesystem level, and just pass on the writes to Chromes HTML5 filesystem code.

Note however that even if an app has "unlimitedStorage", is is still limited by the physical disk space on the system, as well as any other OS level quotas.

You can examine the various use and quota information using the special URL of: chrome://quota-internals.

On my Chromebook Pixel I have just over 2Gb free for the profile directory for example using the guest account. Using a non-guest account shows more like 22Gb.

If you really do seem to have more than 1Gb of free space, feel free to [file a bug](http://goo.gl/megdlG) and we will consider giving it a more serious look.

Note too from what I saw, we do not correctly report free space to the Android app, so writes may fail even though a call to statfs()/android.os.StatFs() seems to indicate there is space left on the device.

Comment: I see the same 1 GB limit using Arc Welder. The internal-storage url says 263GB free. The manifest.json says unlimited storage. a different 256MB file writes and reads just fine.

Comment: @mjstam, Do you remember what happens when you attempt to write more than 1 GB? Do you just get an error, or is the app data wiped on next restart?

Comment: @mjstam, Do you remember what happens when you attempt to write more than 1 GB? Do you just get an error, or is the app data wiped on next restart?